# Bulk data filters in Tableau

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, google-sheets-query

Our organization is in e-commerce and users are looking to change a filter everyday with a different list of items, and none of the users will have their own license, just read-only access. The data is connected through Google Big Query, is there a way to have this bulk filter upload capability without the License owners having to touch the filter each time?

Example
Product ID is the filter

Monday: they have a list of 10,000 ID's they want to check sales for
Tuesday: They have a new list of 4,000 different ID's they want to check sales for.
Without clicking each ID each time, is there a way to just upload a list, csv, google sheet etc.

We thought users can upload a list of Product ids to Google sheets which can map to a BigQuery table. We can use it to join with the sales table and get the relevant data. However this becomes unmanageable when we have more than 1 user as users might step on to others data.

Any suggestions/recommendations are welcome. Our team is pretty new to Tableau as such. Let me know if any additional details are needed.

Comment: You've asked a broad and potentially tricky question that dependsa on details. A complex use case for starting out... If possible, filtering and analysis will be easier and more efficient if people can work with a few higher level discriminators instead of long lists of Ids. So, regardless of visualization tool, think about whether you can factor out higher level smaller flags that your users can use - Items in Category A, processed between these dates, with Status X and POC Y etc There are ways to work with long lists of Ids as filters, but look for alternatives first

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the filter type to "Multi Values (custom list)" and then having the report user paste their list into the filter? See below:

[image]

Comment: Matt,this is something which the users are not comfortable with. They don't want to paste 100's of ids into the filter box.